# pass matrix of values between two activities

Tags: android, android-intent

I can't pass a matrix of integers between two activities. here is the code:

- Activity A:

  `intent.putExtra("matrix_", (Serializable)matrix);`
- Activity B:

  ```
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  matrix =  (int[][]) extras.getSerializable("matrix_");
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are creating an object of intent, you can take advantage of following two methods for passing objects between two activities.

[putParceble](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putParcelable%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable%29)

[putSerializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putSerializable%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable%29)

What you can do with this, is have your class implement either [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) or [Serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html).

Then you can pass around your custom classes across activities. I have found this very useful.

Here is a small snippet of code I am using

```
Matrix matrix  = new Matrix ();
Intent i = new Intent();

Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putParcelable("CUSTOM_LISTING", matrix  );
i.putExtras(b);
i.setClass(this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

And in newly started activity code will be something like this...

```
Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
if(b!=null)
    mCurrentListing = b.getParcelable("CUSTOM_LISTING");
```

** EDITED WITH LINKS:::  **

[LINK1](http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/676a603928950e24/a898ae5c217318e1) consist of sample code

[LINK2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android)

[LINK3](http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/)

Comment: i apologize because I'm still a beginner with programming, i cannot understand how to use your advice. My application, in the first activity, takes as input two matrix and performs the multiplication. in the second activity takes the result of the multiplication from the first activity and displays it

Comment: Seems like Matrix is not parcelable. William's answer worked for me

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer as mentioned above. The links given are for extended subclasses that actually implement `Parcelable`, and `Matrix` clearly isn't one of them.

Answer (score 8):

There is a simple way to pass matrix through intent.

Activity A:

```
float[] values = new float[9];
matrix.getValues(values);
intent.putExtra("matrix_values", values);
```

Activity B:

```
float[] values = getIntent().getFloatArrayExtra("matrix_values");
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setValues(values);
```